# Accordion Table with Bootstrap issue

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table, bootstrap-accordion

I have bootstrap table with accordion

I need hide by default second row

But when I clicked the table moves

How to make the animation and opening smooth, without shifting?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
    <tr data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse">
        <td>Info</td>
        <td>Some more Info</td>
        <td>And some Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="collapse" class="collapse">
        <td>Hidden by default</td>
        <td>Hidden by default</td>
        <td>Hidden by default</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ejdy462h/2/

Comment: Apply `table-layout: fixed` to the table. (That might slightly change the behavior of how the columns are laid out. If that doesn't work for your - then you will probably have to find a different solution than Bootstrap's collapse.)

Answer (score 0):

I purpose to you to use jQuery [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) and [selector attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_end_value.asp)

If you want to use this, you just need to remove `data-bs-toggle="collapse"` from your first tr

```js
$("tr[href$='#collapse']").click(function() {
  $(this).next("tr#collapse:first").fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-hover">
<tbody>
    <tr href="#collapse">
        <td>Info</td>
        <td>Some more Info</td>
        <td>And some Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="collapse" class="collapse">
        <td>Hidden by default</td>
        <td>Hidden by default</td>
        <td>Hidden by default</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```